# Simple example of how to capture traces during OOBE with WPR / ADK

Tags: command-line, freeze, logging, debug, adk

I need to capture traces immediately after OOBE to debug an issue. I was pointed to the Windows Performance Recorder tool provided with the Windows ADK.

All of the instructions I have seen instruct me to launch the WPR GUI. This doesn't work - it simply says "A referral was returned from the server". Searching for help on this issue yields only one old and hard to understand MSDN article.

However, it should be no problem. The command line tool still seems to work. However, all of the examples and docs on this tool seem very convoluted.

**So my question is:**

Can someone please give me the simplest possible example of how to capture traces while coming out of OOBE using the WPR command line tools?

Comment: Does anything in this help https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-165-Performance-tracing-in-OOBE ?

Comment: @DavidMarshall everything in that helps. If you want rep, find a way to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It's not something I know about. I was just aware of the video being posted recently.